# MongoDB - How to return matching documents and number of matching documents in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm struggling to write a mongo aggregation which will return both the matching documents, as well as the number of matching documents for each identifier (in this example, staffId).

I have the following aggregation which works to return the count, but I can't seem to get the matching documents for each staffId.

```
xxx.aggregate([
       // step 1
      {
        $match: obj,
      },
      // step 2
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$staffId",
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

The idea being that this will return an array of objects with the staffId and count. I then want to use each staffId to return the matching documents, to return something like:

```
[{_id: '1234', count: 4, documents: [matching-documents for staff 1234]}, {_id: '5678', count: 12, documents: [matching-documents for staff 5768] } ]
```

Any help is massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$push` the `$$ROOT`, which refers to the document it self in the `$group` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$staffId",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      documents: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0QZ9_QPyNwA)

Comment: I've just done this now, I didn't realise that accepting an answer was something that could be done. Appreciate your help!